# how to implementation VIPS algorithm use gtk webkit？

Tags: webkit, gtk

I need to implementation [VIPS](http://www.zjucadcg.cn/dengcai/VIPS/VIPS.html) algorithm based on gtk webkit,but i can't find any doucumentation about how to use gtk webkit.Does anyone know of a simple "Hello World" example for using gtk Webkit library?And i want to get the color and location of every tag in the html file,can webkit satisfy my requirement？

Apologize for my poor  english！

Answer (score 1):

Some research papers mention using [CSSBox](http://cssbox.sourceforge.net) for implementing the page segmentation. It provides all the functionality you require but it is implemented in Java.